# Wordpress Multisite Server Horizontal Scale on AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, horizontal-scaling

I want to do horizontal scale my single multisite wordpress server. I mean to say that need to run multiple multisite wordpress server of same type. Can any help me How can I do horizontal scaling of multisite wordpress server ( want to run two machines of same multisite wordpress server ).

Comment: Hello, I am confused on what are you trying to achieve. You goal is to Server the same Wordpress code base and content from Multiple EC2 instances in Wordpress ? So that you can add up machines to your cluster in case of need ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, how to scale horizontally multisite wordpress instance on AWS platform. This can be achieved by keeping wordpress directory on AWS EFS filesystem. Apache and php we can keep on EC2 instances. In front of EC2 instances we keep AWS Application loadbalancer with enabling sticky session. This way we can add multiple EC2 instances to handle large number of requests and PHP sessions are maintained through sticky session.